# efficient way of computing a dataframe using concat and split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, assign

I am new to python/pandas/numpy and I need to create the following Dataframe:

```
DF  = pd.concat([pd.Series(x[2]).apply(lambda r: pd.Series(re.split('\@|/',r))).assign(id=x[0]) for x in hDF])
```

where `hDF` is a dataframe that has been created by:

```
hDF=pd.DataFrame(h.DF)
```

and `h.DF` is a list whose elements looks like this:

```
    ['5203906',
 ['highway=primary',
  'maxspeed=30',
  'oneway=yes',
  'ref=N 22',
  'surface=asphalt'],
 ['3655224911@1.735928/42.543651',
  '3655224917@1.735766/42.543561',
  '3655224916@1.735694/42.543523',
  '3655224915@1.735597/42.543474',
  '4817024439@1.735581/42.543469']]
```

However, in some cases the list is very long (O(10^7)) and also the list in `h.DF[*][2]` is very long, so I run out of memory.

I can obtain the same result, avoiding the use of the lambda function, like so:

```
DF  = pd.concat([pd.Series(x[2]).str.split('\@|/', expand=True).assign(id=x[0]) for x in hDF])
```

But I am still running out of memory in the cases where the lists are very long.

Can you think of a possible solution to obtain the same results without starving resources?

Comment: Split your code up so each line does one thing -- it is good practice because such code is easier to understand and debug. For example, I suspect you're having an indexing problem as a result of casting this non-uniform list to a dataframe. You could consider doing your text processing first.

Comment: I don't know how to split the code since it's in a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work using the following code:

```
bl = []
for x in h.DF:
    data = np.loadtxt(
        np.loadtxt(x[2], dtype=str, delimiter="@")[:, 1], dtype=float, delimiter="/"
    ).tolist()
    [i.append(x[0]) for i in data]
    bl.append(data)
bbl = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(bl))
DF = pd.DataFrame(bbl).rename(columns={0: "lon", 1: "lat", 2: "wayid"})
```

Now it's super fast :)